# Sketch: Hide grid for multiple artboards

Tags: sketch-app

After activating the grid for all artboards by accident, I'd like to deactivate it for all of them without selecting each artboard separately and unchecking "Show grid" for each. How can I do that?

Comment: It would be great to have that!

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no any functionality to toggle grid for all artboards by once.

Try this:

1. Select the top artboard
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to deactivate the grid
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the nex artboard
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> go to 3